# Open workbooks that contain a certain string in their file name

Tags: excel, vba

There are 13 files in a folder called `Folder_1`. These 13 files are named like this:

1. `2020-01_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
2. `2020-02_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
3. `2020-03_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
4. `2020-04_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
5. `2020-05_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
6. `2020-06_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
7. `2020-07_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
8. `2020-08_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
9. `2020-09_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
10. `2020-10_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
11. `2020-11_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
12. `2020-12_Template_XYZ.xlsm`
13. `Master_file.xlsm`

`Master_file.xlsm` contains a macro that looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenWorksheets()

Dim workbook_1 As Workbook
Dim workbook_2 As Workbook
Dim workbook_3 As Workbook
Dim workbook_4 As Workbook
Dim workbook_5 As Workbook
Dim workbook_6 As Workbook
Dim workbook_7 As Workbook
Dim workbook_8 As Workbook
Dim workbook_9 As Workbook
Dim workbook_10 As Workbook
Dim workbook_11 As Workbook
Dim workbook_12 As Workbook
Dim active_workbook As Workbook

Set workbook_1 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-01_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_2 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-02_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_3 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-03_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_4 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-04_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_5 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-05_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_6 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-06_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_7 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-07_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_8 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-08_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_9 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-09_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_10 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-10_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_11 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-11_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set workbook_12 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2020-12_Template_XYZ.xlsm")
Set active_workbook = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)

End Sub
```

`Folder_2` also contains 13 files. These 13 files are named like this:

1. `2021-01_Template_ABC.xlsm`
2. `2021-02_Template_ABC.xlsm`
3. `2021-03_Template_ABC.xlsm`
4. `2021-04_Template_ABC.xlsm`
5. `2021-05_Template_ABC.xlsm`
6. `2021-06_Template_ABC.xlsm`
7. `2021-07_Template_ABC.xlsm`
8. `2021-08_Template_ABC.xlsm`
9. `2021-09_Template_ABC.xlsm`
10. `2021-10_Template_ABC.xlsm`
11. `2021-11_Template_ABC.xlsm`
12. `2021-12_Template_ABC.xlsm`
13. `Master_file.xlsm`

If the macro code in `Master_file.xlsm` did not change, I would have to adapt the macro accordingly by writing code that looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenWorksheets()

Dim workbook_1 As Workbook
Dim workbook_2 As Workbook
Dim workbook_3 As Workbook
Dim workbook_4 As Workbook
Dim workbook_5 As Workbook
Dim workbook_6 As Workbook
Dim workbook_7 As Workbook
Dim workbook_8 As Workbook
Dim workbook_9 As Workbook
Dim workbook_10 As Workbook
Dim workbook_11 As Workbook
Dim workbook_12 As Workbook
Dim active_workbook As Workbook

Set workbook_1 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-01_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_2 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-02_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_3 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-03_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_4 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-04_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_5 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-05_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_6 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-06_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_7 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-07_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_8 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-08_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_9 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-09_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_10 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-10_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_11 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-11_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set workbook_12 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-12_Template_ABC.xlsm")
Set active_workbook = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)

End Sub
```

Instead of doing this, I would like the macro code of `Master_file.xlsm` to be able to look for files in its folder where the file names contain the string `-01_Template_`, `-02_Template_`, …, `-12_Template_` and assign them to `workbook_1`, `workbook_2`, …, `workbook_12`.

Writing something like `Set workbook_1 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*-01_Template_*.xlsm")` does not work and I have inspected countless other questions regarding the problems with changing file names.

So, how can I solve the problem that I just described?

Comment: Did you try using [`Dir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But this did not work. What is your suggestion?

Comment: a problem will be that you want a differently named variable for each since there's no easy way to increment the variable name

Comment: Would be helpful to show how you tried `Dir`.

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found the answer. The solution is to write something like this:

```
Set workbook_1 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Dir(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "*-01_Template_*.xlsm"))
```

Instead of something like this:

```
Set workbook_1 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Dir(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*-01_Template_*.xlsm"))
```

The first asterisk `*` seems to require a certain position in order to be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Dir.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Otherwise consider constructing part of the path into a string variable and appending the part that changes, then passing that variable into your open command.

For example, you could put:

```
Dim sPathLeader$
sPathLeader = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-"
```

Then, where you have the following line:

```
Set workbook_1 = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2021-01_Template_ABC.xlsm")
```

You could replace it with:

```
Set workbook_1 = Workbooks.Open(sPathLeader & "01_Template_ABC.xlsm")
```

Then, if you have lots of years, you could put the whole thing in a `For` loop, where each iteration starts by rebuilding sPathLader with a different year.

But, that is less optimal, though it may help if in a pinch in a single use case.

It is better to use Dir to determine the filenames in that path dynamically.

Otherwise, you will have a lot of validation checking and error trapping to do, to set up how to react if a file name is not found etc.

Answer (score 0):

The below code can be used to get a list of file names in a directory.  You can then open each file up one at at time.

```
Public Function Test()

    Dim dirPath As String: dirPath = "C:\Temp\"     ' must end in \
    Dim coll As Collection
    Set coll = GetFilesInDirectory(dirPath, "*.*")
    Dim fileName As Variant
    For Each fileName In coll
        Debug.Print dirPath & fileName
    Next fileName
    
End Function

Public Function GetFilesInDirectory(dirPath As String, Optional criteria As String = "*.*") As Collection
    
    ' Send in a directory path and criteria for file names (*.*) ; directory must end in \
    ' Returns all files names found that are like criteria ; does not return directories

    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = dir(dirPath & criteria)
    Do While fileName <> ""
        coll.Add fileName
        fileName = dir
    Loop
    Set GetFilesInDirectory = coll
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have so many individual workbook objects you want to refer to then you could do something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim workbook1 As Workbook, workbook2 As Workbook, active_workbook As Workbook

Set active_workbook = ThisWorkbook '? not sure why this wouldn't be okay in your case     since this runs from master book

For i = 1 To 12:
    Select Case i:
    Case i = 1:
        Set workbook1 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2020-" & Format(i, "00") & "_Template_ABC.xlsm")
    Case i = 2:
        Set workbook2 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2020-" & Format(i, "00") & "_Template_ABC.xlsm")
    'you get the pattern i'm sure
    End Select
Next i
end sub
```

There may be better ways to organize any dependent code though, like looping through and working with each workbook one at a time, instead of needing all of them handed over at once.